# Font Awesome Not Loading - Only for Client

Tags: font-awesome, kentico

Our client is running Kentico 9 and is experiencing issues loading the icon fonts from Font Awesome. If this is a Kentico related issue, we’d like to get it figured out ASAP. That said, the client is experiencing these issues internally; on their network. Everyone else outside of their offices is able to see them without issue. They have whitelisted the URLs for the CDN that serves up the icons and when doing so – they are able to see the icons. Assistance or direction on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using the embed JS code provided by Font Awesome. Should I simply not use the CDN and use local files?

Comment: I think I would try local files first, to rule out any issue with the actual files. If the local files load, then it must be some routing issue to the CDN location. I would recommend using Fiddler or some other tool to see the response that is being returned for the CDN path.

Comment: Serving local files seems to have resolved the issue. I honestly thought loading from CDN would be better/faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have had this problem once, Downloading font-awesome files and serving them from the same server where it was consumed solved the purpose for me.

I experienced similar problems as you faced.

Below is the site on which I faced this https://www.landolakesinc.com/

Cheers,
Chetan

Comment: Serving local files seems to have resolved the issue. I honestly thought loading from CDN would be better/faster

Comment: Thanks @SalB, kindly mark it as a correct answer so that it may help others too.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion and best practice is to always use local files/resources.  They load faster and you don't have to worry about uptime with the CDN providing those resources.

Knowing this doesn't solve your immediate issue without some work, I'd look into the web.config to ensure you have proper file types allowed. I believe they are added by default in v9 but make sure you have at least the following extenstions mapped:

`<mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff"/>`
`<mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/x-font-woff2"/>`
`<mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml"/>`

Comment: Thanks! Serving local files seems to have resolved the issue. I honestly thought loading from CDN would be better/faster.

Answer (score 0):

Also, do the internal folks access the site from an ip address? I have had internal sites not show any font icons, including kenticos because of the ip address.  Once I switched it over to an actual domain name, it worked perfectly.  Just a thought, as I have seen that happen before.

Comment: It's on an azure staging URL, not IP. Serving local files seems to have resolved the issue.